# Adding Field Tags in Plain Text

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Reportlab to generate a PDF that I eventually send to DocuSign via the API. How can I add a signature to my document? Does something like {signature:user1______} exist where I can have this in plain text and DocuSign will realize it and add a signature there once the envelope is uploaded?

I added this code here for a signature tab and when I sent the envelope, no signature tab was added. Any reason why?

```
'tabs': {
        'signHereTabs': [
            {
                'anchorString': '//SIGN_HERE//'
                'anchorUnits': 'pixels',
                'anchorXOffest': '0',
                'anchorYOffest': '0',
                'name': 'Please Sign Here',
                'optional': 'false',
                'recipientId': '1',
                'tabLabel': 'signHere'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Also, when I received the document to sign via email, I was allowed to drag fields onto the document. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use anchor text to locate where to place DocuSign fields on the page. But DocuSign won't delete your anchor text.

The usual answer is to use the page's background color (white) as the text color for your anchor text.

Or, if you can create a PDF signing area, DocuSign can convert it to a DocuSign sign here field

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Check out the concepts section of the DocuSign developer center